# How to make a Silverlight Out Of Browser application start maximised

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to make an Out of Browser application start maximised?

You can set Left, Top, Height & Width properties when configuring the Out of Browser settings but I cannot see a way to make the application maximised.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
{
     Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
     Application.Current.MainWindow.TopMost = true;
}
```

Comment: Why TopMost = true ? This is blocking Visual studio when debugging.